# Excel VBA: usage of Dialog(xlDialogProtectDocument).Show

Tags: vba, excel

I want to preset the *Protect Sheet* dialog of Excel. I want it preset as in this screenshot:
[image: First three checkboxes set]

One way to open this dialog with some preset is:

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogProtectDocument).Show arg1:=True
```

This sets/unsets the first checkbox in the dialog.

According to the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838781%28v=office.15%29.aspx) the allowed arguments are:

```
contents, windows, password, objects, scenarios
```

Some trial and error did not reveal if and how one can preset the checkboxes in the bottom list.

Is that possible? If yes, how?

Comment: If you want to preset with static options, then why not just protect the sheet, ticking the options you want to enable, and then unprotect again. The next time someone goes to protect the sheet, the previous options chosen will be retained.

Comment: You are right. Excel actually *does* remember the previous setting. Reason I didn't notice is that in my project there are loads of VBA macros that set and unset the protection (via `.unprotect`/`.protect`) on that sheet, which messes up the preset (and the protection of the sheet itself!). This insight might actually make this question irrelevant to my specific case. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

As noticed by lturner in a comment the dialog remembers the previous setting used. This *does* include the settings used when setting the sheet protection via VBA. Thus setting + unsetting the protection via VBA prior to opening the dialog with

```
Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Protect AllowFormattingCells:=True
Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Unprotect
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogProtectDocument).Show
```

does produce the checkbox as wanted.

A list of all possible options to the `.Protect` method is given on the [official documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff840611.aspx).

*This is an ugly solution as it's has side effects (the sheet is shortly protected in the process) and is based on side effects. I will thus not accept this answer for now. Better answers are welcome and will be accepted.*